# R syntax explanation needed

Tags: r, syntax

R beginner:
trying to understand code within a for loop to adapt to my own dataset

--> Can someone please explain what the syntax "5" does/means in the last line of this code part of a for-loop head:

```
vd_ID <- c(unique(vd$Respondent))

id <- (vd_ID[i])

x <- c(1:length(as.numeric(vd[vd$Respondent == id, 5])))
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's the column number, section 5.3 in [R-intro](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) that comes with your and every distribution of R. Also, the `c()` in the first line can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `5` is a column index. In this case, it is specifying that you want to return the fifth column of object `vd`. More precisely, it is specifying that you want the fifth element of the vector of columns for object $vd$.

When working with a `data.frame` like I suspect `vd` to be, you can extract rows and columns using `vd[rows,columns]` where you can replace `rows` with a number or vector of numbers to specify the row(s) to get and replace `columns` with a number or vector of numbers to specify the column(s) to get. If you omit `rows` or `columns`, R assumes you want all of the rows or columns. For example `vd[3, ]` is row 3 for all columns while `vd[ ,2]` is column 2 for all rows. Similarly, `vd[ ,2:5 ]` gets all rows for the 2nd through 5th columns.